# ARM Pipeline for iterate through all resources in same subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-task-groups

I have to create a pipeline that run the tasks for all the SQL Managed Instances in same subscription, each SQL Managed Instance has it's own Resource Group. I want to avoid to write the name of the resource in the pipeline as parameter because every week we create a lot of new SQL managed instances. I need to add a step in the pipeline that iterate through all the type  "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances" without specifying the name of the resource in the pipeline.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

parameters:
  - name: resourceConfigurations
    type: object
    default:
     - { resourceGroup: 'PROD_BAZ_MISQL01' }
     - { resourceGroup: 'PROD_BGT_MISQL01-asr' }

jobs:
- job: DeployMetricAlerts
  displayName: 'Deploy Metric Alerts'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

  steps:
  - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: 'Deploy metric alert for CPU utilization'
      inputs:
            deploymentScope: Resource Group
            azureResourceManagerConnection: ADO_Pipeline_AI
            subscriptionId: 
            resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceConfigurations[0].resourceGroup }}
            location: "Global"
            templateLocation: Linked artifact
            csmFile: '**/Templates/metric_alert_static.json'
            csmParametersFile: '**/Parameter_Files/CPU_usage_SQL_managed_ins.json'
            deploymentMode: Incremental
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      displayName: Deploy metric alert for IO request count
      inputs:
            deploymentScope: Resource Group
            azureResourceManagerConnection: ADO_Pipeline_AI
            subscriptionId: 
            resourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.resourceConfigurations[0].resourceGroup }}
            location: "Global"
            templateLocation: Linked artifact
            csmFile: '**/Templates/metric_alert_dynamic.json'
            csmParametersFile: '**/Parameter_Files/IO_req_count.json'
            deploymentMode: Incremental
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the way below.

Have two pipelines (**Pipe01** and **Pipe02**).

---

###### In Pipe01, set the following steps in the same job.

1. Use the [AzureCLI@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run the "[**`az sql mi list`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/mi?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-mi-list)" get a list of names for all the managed instances.

   ```yaml
   - task: AzureCLI@2
     displayName: 'List name of managed instances'
     inputs:
       azureSubscription: {ARM Service Connection}
       scriptType: bash
       scriptLocation: inlineScript
       inlineScript: 'az sql mi list --query "[].name"'
   ```

   - The **`{ARM Service Connection}`** is an [**Azure Resource Manager service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection) to connect to the Azure subscription.
   - The parameter '**`--query "[].name"`**' can extract the names of all managed instances as an array from the output. For example.

     ```json
     [
       "my-sqlmi-01",
       "my-sqlmi-02"
     ]
     ```
2. Use a [Bash@3 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines) to call the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Runs - Run Pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)" to trigger **Pipe02** and pass the name list of managed instances as the value of a parameter to **Pipe02**.

   ```yaml
   - task: Bash@3
     displayName: 'Trigger Pipe02'
     env:
       SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
     inputs:
       targetType: inline
       script: |
         uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.0"
         curl -X POST -u :$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN $uri \
         -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         -d '{
             "templateParameters": {
             "SqlManagedInstances": "[\"my-sqlmi-01\", \"my-sqlmi-02\"]"
             }
         }'
   ```

---

###### In Pipe02, set like as below.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: SqlManagedInstances
  type: object

. . .

steps:
- ${{ each Instance in parameters.SqlManagedInstances }}:
  - bash: echo "Instance = ${{ Instance }}"
    displayName: 'Show each Instance'

  - Some other steps you need to run with the name of each instance
```

---

Comment: @Sissi_00_20, Is there any update from you? Have you checked the steps shared in my above answer to dynamically set the values of a pipeline parameter? Is it helpful for you?